# Solving Absolute-Value Equations of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I just started doing A-Level Further Maths and I am unsure of how to solve this question: $|z-3|= |z-1|$

I understand that with $|z| = 1$ you would get a circle of a radius of 1 on the origin on the argand diagram however I'm not sure what you would do for the question above.

(Sorry if there are any formatting mistakes or errors, new to this)

Comment: New?  Welcome to the site!  As for formatting... http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you for the help :D

Comment: Use http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com for more casual math chatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $z=x+iy$ then your equation is equivalent to
$$(x-3)^2+y^2=|z-3|^2=|z-1|^2=(x-1)^2+y^2.$$
After the algebraic solution. Are you able to solve the problem also from the geometric point of view?
Note that you are looking for the points whose distances from 1 and 3 are the same. That is the [line segment bisector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection) of the real segment $[1,3]$ whose equation is $x=2$ or $\mbox{Re}(z)=2$.

P.S. In general $|z-u|= |z-v|$ is the line segment bisector of the segment of extreme point $u$ and $v$. The equation of this line can be found by solving
$$(x-u_x)^2+(y-u_y)^2=(x-v_x)^2+(y-v_y)^2$$
where $u=u_x+iu_y$ and  $v=v_x+iv_y$. Finally we get
$$(v_x-u_x) x+(v_y-u_y)y=\frac{|v|^2-|u|^2}{2}.$$

Comment: I need to show a set of solutions so the answer would have to be in a geometric point of view

Comment: @SylentNyte Note the $y^2$'s would cancel out, so any value of $y$ plus the correct values of $x$ will satisfy the problem.  Its a straight line along $x=\dots$

Comment: @SimpleArt, got it, x = 2, thank you!

Comment: @Sylent Nyte Line segment bisector is the key-word.

Comment: @RobertZ Meh, no need to confuse him.  I think $z=2+iy$ is fine.

Comment: @SimpleArt if one of them where to be | z + j |, what is that equivalent to?

Comment: @SylentNyte Use exact same process RobertZ used, and you should find the answer is very similar/simple.

Comment: @SimpleArt I followed the example, problem is |z - 1| = |z + i| and i simplified it to x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 = x^2 + 1, is this correct because I dont think it is?

Comment: @Sylent Nyte It should be $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + (y+1)^2$.

Comment: @SylentNyte The $+i$ contributes to the $iy$, not the $x$.  And it is merely an addition: $i(y+1)$.  It simplifies to the more general $z=a+ai$

Comment: Ah ha, gotcha, so the real number in the equation is added onto x whereas the imaginary number is added to y, that makes sense

Comment: @SylentNyte Yes.  The initial statement $z=x+iy$ assumes $x,y\in\mathbb R$ so that we may consider them separately.

Answer (score 1):

$\left| {z - c} \right| = r$ is a circle of radius r with center at $c+0i$, so
$\left| {z - 1} \right| = r = \left| {z - 3} \right|$ clearly is the intersection of ..., all which stay on a ...

Answer (score 1):

$|z-3|=|z-1|$ is the locus of points $z$ in the complex plane that are equidistant from $3$ and $1$. It is geometrically obvious that this is the vertical line $\Re(z) = 2$.

For a calculation leading to the same result, square both sides of the equality and use $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$:

$$(z-3)(\bar z - 3) = (z - 1)(\bar z - 1)$$

$$z \bar z -3(z + \bar z) + 9 = z \bar z -(z + \bar z) + 1$$

$$ 2(z+\bar z) = 8$$
$$ z+\bar z = 4$$

Since $z+\bar z = 2 \;\Re(z)$ the latter simplifies to $\Re(z) = 2$.